# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead allowNew select-on-blur

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Is it possible to configure this so when allowNew is set that any new entry in this field would be selected on blur rather than clicking on the new item "menu"

EDITED:
This is my existing child component

```
<Typeahead
   labelKey="label"
   allowNew
   selectHintOnEnter
   options={props.campaignOptions}
   placeholder="Campaign Name..."
   onChange={props.campaignName}
 />
```

And this is my parent component...

```
campaignName (campaign){
  campaign.length ? this.setState({campaignSelected:campaign}) : this.setState({campaignSelected:''})
  }
```

...

```
<FormGroup>
    <Campaign
     campaignName={this.campaignName.bind(this)}
     campaignOptions={[...new Set(this.props.records.map(options => options.campaign))]}/>
 </FormGroup>
```

Comment: What behavior are you looking for and how does the current behavior not meet your requirements? If you pass an empty array to `options`, anything the user enters will be considered new, but they will still need to select the option from the menu.

Comment: Hi @ericgio I wanted a user to be able to type into the field and if it did not exist in options they it would be classed as new when you lost focus  - you would not have to select new item in the menu

Comment: So really what you're asking about is select-on-blur behavior. Can you edit your question to clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice, but I managed to get this to work with a much simpler approach that means that I don't need to use onBlur and I just store the onInputChange in the state in the parent.

```
  const {campaignOptions, campaignValue, campaignName} = this.props;

  ...

<Typeahead
    labelKey="label"
      allowNew
      placeholder="Campaign Name..."
      onInputChange={campaignName}
      options={campaignOptions}
      selected={campaignValue}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in the single-select case. Here's how you could do it:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: [],
    text: '',
  };

  render() {
    const {selected, text} = this.state;

    return (
      <Typeahead
        allowNew
        onBlur={(e) => this.setState({selected: text ? [text] : []})}
        onChange={selected => this.setState({selected})}
        onInputChange={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        options={this.props.options}
        selected={selected}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the code above simply sets the input value as the selection. You most likely want to convert the string to an object that has a unique identifier, like an ID.

It's not possible to do it in the multi-select case because you'd need to clear just the text input (not the selections) after the selecting the text, and there's no API for doing that.

Comment: Thanks @ericgio. My component is currently an FSC. What is the best way to pass this up as a prop or should I convert to a class based component?

Comment: You can move state up to the parent, though as a rule of thumb in React, state shouldn't be moved any higher than it absolutely needs to. I don't know what your code looks like, so you need to be the ultimate judge there. If you move state up to the parent, you can just pass everything down as props to your FSC, eg: `props.onBlur`, `props.onChange`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll convert to be class based

Comment: Sorry to be dim @ericgio, but I have converted this to a class based component and can't get this to work with my props I am passing down. Would you be kind enough to pass any words of wisdom on? I have edited the question with my code which works without the onBlur functionality

Comment: @NickWild: For starters, your code doesn't have an `onBlur` callback, so nothing happens when you blur the input. You also need an `onInputChange` callback to track the state of the text input's value.